# How to add Currency Symbol( Rupees Symbol) in .pdf with Times Font using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, currency, tcpdf

I am generating a PDF file, using MYHTML2PDF library in PHP, and the font type is **times**. I want to show the INR (Rupees) symbol in the pdf.

Rupees Symbol's code '₹' is working fine on web but not working in downloading pdf file. It shows '?' symbol.

---

**Using following code: (but its not working fine)**

```
$html2pdf = new MyHtml2Pdf('P','A4','en', true, 'UTF-8');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont("times",'B',8);
$html2pdf->writeHTML($table, true, false, false, false, '');
$html2pdf->output($file_name , 'F');
```

Comment: IIRC the times font of TCPDF did not include many unicode symbols. I ended up using dejavuserif, I believe.

Comment: Is it possible If rupees symbol's hexa code added to times font, then we will get solution for download pdf